# Get the current input value with the same class names

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to alert the current value that is in the input box depending on which button you click on. So if the first grid-2 button is selected it would alert 1 and if the second button with the input value of 2 was to be clicked on instead it would alert that number etc.

```
<div class='grid-2'>
    <input class="photo1" value="1">
    <a class='remove-photo' href='#'>Remove Now</a>
</div>

<div class='grid-2'>
    <input class="photo1" value="2">
    <a class='remove-photo' href='#'>Remove Now</a>
</div>


<div class='grid-2'>
    <input class="photo1" value="3">
    <a class='remove-photo' href='#'>Remove Now</a>
</div>


<div class='grid-2'>
    <input class="photo1" value="4">
    <a class='remove-photo' href='#'>Remove Now</a>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".remove-photo").click(function() {
        var current_selected_photo_num = $(".photo1").val();
        alert(current_selected_photo_num);
    });
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: Take a look at my answer, see if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can locate the surrounding `div` and find the `input` in it:

```
$(".remove-photo").click(function() {
    var num = $(this).closest('div').find(".photo1").val();
    alert(num);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the `.prev()` function to go upwards through siblings

```
$(".remove-photo").click(function() { 
    var current_selected_photo_num = 
    $(this).prev('.photo1').val(); 
    alert(current_selected_photo_num); 
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a fan of any listed answer so far, they are all tightly coupled to html which makes your javascript fragile.  A simple HTML change could prevent most other answers from working as expected.

Instead I would suggest changing your HTML:

```
<input class="photo1" value="1" id="photo-1-1">
<a class='remove-photo js-remove-photo' href='#' data-alert-target="#photo-1-1">Remove Now</a>

<input class="photo1" value="1" id="photo-1-2">
<a class='remove-photo js-remove-photo' href='#' data-alert-target="#photo-1-2">Remove Now</a>

<input class="photo1" value="1" id="photo-1-3">
<a class='remove-photo js-remove-photo' href='#' data-alert-target="#photo-1-3">Remove Now</a>

<input class="photo1" value="1" id="photo-1-4">
<a class='remove-photo js-remove-photo' href='#' data-alert-target="#photo-1-4">Remove Now</a>
```

Javascript

```
$(".js-remove-photo").click(function() {
  var target = $(this).data('alert-target');
  var value = $(target).val();
  alert(value);
});
```

I'd also recommend reading [Decoupling Your HTML, CSS, and JavaScript - Philip Walton (Engineer at Google)](http://philipwalton.com/articles/decoupling-html-css-and-javascript/).

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery's [.siblings()](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) you can get the siblings of the element as the selector and specify a class or ID that the sibling should have. Then it's just a matter of getting the value of the sibling and alerting it.

```
$(".remove-photo").on("click", function(){
    var inputValue = $(this).siblings(".photo1").val();
    alert(inputValue);
});
```